# Помогите распарсить html

Tags: html, парсер, php, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите пожалуйста распарсить html. 
Мне нужно заносить данные в массив по такому принципу:

```
$mas[0]=array(00094318,4 500,id5869445320,2014-08-03&nbsp;14:48);

$mas[1]=array(00094366,5 500,id58694453765,2014-08-03&nbsp;14:48);
```

Я пробовал распарсить:

```
preg_match_all('/\<td class="td[0-9]( text_right){0,1}"\>(.){0,}\<\/td\>/U',$html,$data);
```

Но мой вариант работает не совсем корректно.

```
<table class="table2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<tr class="tr_head">
<td class="td_head">Отправитель</td>
<td class="td_head" style="width:70px">Сумма, руб.</td>
<td class="td_head" style="width:310px">Комментарий</td>
<td class="td2">Дата проведения</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr1" onmouseover="onMouseOver(this, '')" onmouseout="onMouseOut(this, '', 'tr1')">
<td class="td1">00094318</td><td class="td1 text_right">4 500</td>
<td class="td1">id5869445320</td>
<td class="td2">2014-08-03&nbsp;14:48</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr1" onmouseover="onMouseOver(this, '')" onmouseout="onMouseOut(this, '', 'tr1')">
<td class="td1">00094366</td><td class="td1 text_right">5 500</td>
<td class="td1">id58694453765</td>
<td class="td2">2014-08-03&nbsp;14:48</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr6">
<td class="padding_5_0 td2">Количество операций: <b>1</b></td>
<td class="td2 text_right bold">4 500</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Парсить HTML с помощью регулярок, на мой взгляд и взгляд очень многих - это извращение. Для таких вещей есть соответствующие инструменты: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) или [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (примеры [найдёте тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/)), или даже с помощью встроенных средст PHP. Вот ваша задача, реализованная с помощью [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) и без подключения каких-либо еще сторонних библиотек:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("file.html"); // путь к вашему файлу
$table = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
$data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($table->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
    foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td){
        $data[$i][] = htmlentities(utf8_decode($td->nodeValue), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($data);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Отправитель
            [1] => Сумма, руб.
            [2] => Комментарий
            [3] => Дата проведения
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00094318
            [1] => 4 500
            [2] => id5869445320
            [3] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00094366
            [1] => 5 500
            [2] => id58694453765
            [3] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Количество операций: 1
            [1] => 4 500
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, хотел уточнить: но ведь нагрузку наверное preg_match_all будет меньше давать, нежели если через DOM работать?

Comment: Регулярка - не только грузящая в плане ресурсов сервера, но еще и грузящая на мозги.

Comment: Спс. Респект )